# Не работает программа C++

Tags: c++, строки

Программа должна убирать лишние пробелы, посмотрел в отладчике, программа работает вроде норм, но потом где-то ломается и выдает ошибку, если кто-то знает из-за чего и что надо исправить, заранее спасибо.

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    string str1("Алексей   Игорь   Валентин   Егор   ");
    string str2;
    int count = str1.size();
    int prb = 0;
    str2.swap(str1);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (int(str2[i]) == 32 || int(str2[i]) == -50)
        {
            for (int a = i; a < count; a++)
            {
                if (int(str2[a]) != 32 && int(str2[a]) != -50)
                {
                    break;
                }
                prb++;
            }
            for (int d = 0; d < prb - 1; d++)
            {
                str2.erase(i + d, 1);
            }
        }
        prb = 0;
    }
    cout << str2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: И? Где описание того, что должна делать эта программа? Как из вашего скриншота можно увидеть, в какой строке произошла эта ошибка?

Comment: Сори, исправил)

Comment: Думаю во внутриннем цикле нужно исправить на int a = i + 1.

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло

Comment: Что означает магическая константа `-50`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `erase` изменяет размер строки, но это не учитывается в условии цикла. Также счетчик внутриннего цикла должен начинаться с `i + 1`. Еще можно не писать `erase` в цикле, так как можно просто передать вторым аргументом количество удаляемых символов.
PS. Ваш алгоритм оставляет один пробел после последнего слова.

Вот немного отредактированный код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str1("Alex    Olya    Bob   ");
    std::string str2 = str1;
    int prb = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str2.size(); i++)
    {
        if (str2[i] == ' ')
        {
            for (int a = i + 1; a < str2.size(); a++)
            {
                if (str2[a] != ' ')
                {
                    break;
                }
                prb++;
            }
            str2.erase(i, prb);
        }
        prb = 0;
    }
    if (str2.back() == ' ') // Удаление последнего пробела
        str2.pop_back();
    std::cout << str2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```